# Magento 2: Error in publishing new extesnion

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation, dashboard

I was trying to submit my **extension** in **Magento dashboard**, after submitting I get these errors.

All others are passed.

Installation & **Varnish** Test Results. Can anyone help in this issue. it's clean code.

```
Autoload error: Module 'Magento_AdminNotification' from '/var/www/html/vendor/way2enjoy/way2enjoy' has been already defined in '/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-admin-notification'.
```

Any help will be great.

here is full `composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "way2enjoy/magento2",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "Make",
  "keywords": [
    "tinify",
    "tinypng",
  ],

  "homepage": "https://way2enjoy.com/developers",
  "license": "MIT",

  "support": {
    "email": "support@way2enjoy.com"
  },

  "authors": [{
    "name": "Rolf Timmermans",
    "email": "rolftimmermans@voormedia.com"
  }],

  "minimum-stability": "alpha",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "way2enjoy/way2enjoy": ">=1.5"
  },
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/way2enjoy2/tinify-php.git"
        }
    ],
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "mikey179/vfsstream": "~1",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0",
    "codeception/aspect-mock": "*"
  },

  "autoload": {
    "files": ["registration.php"],
    "psr-4": {"Way2enjoy\\Magento\\": "src"}
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your Extension vendor/module name ?

Comment: @mohit-chauhan way2enjoy..................

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your composer file for the extension.

I hope, you may have the problem in autoload section of composer file.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "./registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Way2enjoy\\Way2enjoy\\": ""
    }
 }
```

Comment: plx refer updated question added full composer.json

Comment: can you confirm what is your module name here? because the below error message shows "/var/www/html/vendor/way2enjoy/way2enjoy" -> it means way2enjoy as namespace and module name also same. but your composer file shows "way2enjoy / magento"

Comment: namespace way2enjoy\Magento\Model\Config;

use way2enjoy;